# Not Able to output to Label (C#)

Tags: c#, string, label

I am trying to output data to a label but it is not outputting.

The data that I am outputting is a Double that is to be converted to a string. This is my code so far.`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cboGender.SelectedText == "Male")
    {
        dblAge = Convert.ToDouble(txtAge.Text);
        dblWeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtWeight);
        dblHeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtHeight);

        // BMR Calculation
        dblBmrResult = 4.536 * dblWeight + 15.88 * dblHeight - 5 * dblAge + 5;
        strBmrResultConvert = Convert.ToString(dblBmrResult);

        //Output
        lblBmrResult.Text = dblBmrResult.ToString();
    }
    else if (cboGender.SelectedText == "Female")
    {
        dblAge = Convert.ToDouble(txtAge.Text);
        dblWeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtWeight);
        dblHeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtHeight);

        // BMR Calculation
        dblBmrResult = 4.536 * dblWeight + 15.88 * dblHeight - 5 * dblAge + 5;
        strBmrResultConvert = Convert.ToString(dblBmrResult);

        //Output
        lblBmrResult.Text = dblBmrResult.ToString();
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine. Any help to show what I am missing or when wrong will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are those blocks even entered? Doing equality-checks on a string is notoriously likely to fail. And thus it would be easy for neither of the two to run. Consider adding  else for "Invalid Gender Selection".

Comment: @Christopher Will this prevent the data from being outputted?

Comment: Only one of the parts of a if/else/else if/else will run. And it is really important you know wich one so you can fix your comparision. You could also use a swtich/case using the default for the error message. Slightly easier to read. But it is very limited in the allowed checks, comapred to a if.

Comment: Scanning your code visually, I do not see any difference between the logic for male and the logic for female. Is there something missing? Why do you have two `if` blocks?

Comment: @JohnWu I guess those numbers such as `15.88` should be different based on Male/Female. A great case in point for not using magic numbers.

Comment: Is your Label in the visible Range ? Does it already contain data on startup so that you can see it ? Has it Autosize set to true and Visible set to true , or is it's size large enough to show the data (so Width>20, Height >15). Is the label added to a parent control at all, or is it just created ?

Comment: FYI, You have the exact same code in both cases...

Comment: SelectedText isn't what you think it is.  It's the *highlighted* portion of the text string.  `txtWeight` looks like a TextBox control, so it should probably be `txtWeight.Text`  Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @LarsTech This should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Honestly, this is more about understanding the *Basal Metabolic Rate* (BMR) thing that mentioned in the question. I believe the valuable comments up there were enough to solve the main problem of the OP.

How about creating a helper class for that BMR that contains a static function to do the required calculation according to the passed arguments, and another static function to calculate the daily calorie requirement:

```cs
public sealed class BmrHelper
{
    #region enums

    public enum Gender
    {
        Female,
        Male,
    }

    public enum CalcUnit
    {
        Imperial,
        Metric,
    }

    public enum ActivityLevel 
    {
        Sedentary,
        LightlyActive,
        ModeratelyActive,
        VeryActive,
        SuperActive,
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    private BmrHelper() { }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    //Basal Metabolic Rate
    public static double BMR(
        Gender gender, 
        int age, 
        double weight, 
        double height, 
        CalcUnit calcUnit = CalcUnit.Imperial
        )
    {
        var weightFactor = 0D;
        var heightFactor = 0D;
        var bmr = 0D;

        switch (calcUnit)
        {
            case CalcUnit.Metric:
                weightFactor = 10D;
                heightFactor = 6.25D;
                break;
            case CalcUnit.Imperial:
                weightFactor = 4.536D;
                heightFactor = 15.88D;
                break;
        }

        switch(gender)
        {
            case Gender.Female:
                bmr = (weightFactor * weight) + (heightFactor * height) - (5 * age) - 161;
                break;
            case Gender.Male:
                bmr = (weightFactor * weight) + (heightFactor * height) - (5 * age) + 5;
                break;
        }

        return bmr;
    }

    //Calories Per Day
    public static double CPD(
        Gender gender, 
        int age, 
        double weight, 
        double height,
        ActivityLevel activityLevel,
        CalcUnit calcUnit = CalcUnit.Imperial
        )
    {
        var bmr = BMR(gender, age, weight, height, calcUnit);

        return CPD(bmr, activityLevel);
    }

    public static double CPD(double bmr, ActivityLevel activityLevel)
    {
        var alv = 0D;

        switch(activityLevel)
        {
            case ActivityLevel.Sedentary:
                alv = 1.2D;
                break;
            case ActivityLevel.LightlyActive:
                alv = 1.375D;
                break;
            case ActivityLevel.ModeratelyActive:
                alv = 1.55D;
                break;
            case ActivityLevel.VeryActive:
                alv = 1.725D;
                break;
            case ActivityLevel.SuperActive:
                alv = 1.9D;
                break;
        }

        return bmr * alv;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In your implementation, assuming you have a gender combo box with Female and Male items respectively, text boxes for age, weight, and height inputs. A label to show the result:

> Also, you may want to add one more combo box to pass the unit of the
>   factors. Imperial and Metric items respectively. If you want to
>   calculate the daily calorie requirement, then you need another combo
>   box to list the *ActivityLevels* in the same order of the enum.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Validate the inputs

    if (cboGender.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

    if (!int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out int age))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Age...");
        return;
    }


    if (!double.TryParse(txtWeight.Text, out double weight))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Weight...");
        return;
    }

    if (!double.TryParse(txtHeight.Text, out double height))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Height...");
        return;
    }

    //

    var gender = (BmrHelper.Gender)cboGender.SelectedIndex;

    var bmr = BmrHelper.BMR(gender, age, weight, height);

    //or this to use the metric unit instead of the default imperial unit.
    //var bmr = BmrHelper.BMR(gender, age, weight, height, BmrHelper.CalcUnit.Metric);

    lblBmrResult.Text = bmr.ToString();

    //To get the CPD:

    var activityLevel = (BmrHelper.ActivityLevel)cboActivityLevel.SelectedIndex;

    var cpd = BmrHelper.CPD(bmr, activityLevel);

    //or the overload:
    //var cpd = BmrHelper.CPD(
    //    gender,
    //    age,
    //    weight,
    //    height,
    //    activityLevel
    //    );
}
```

According to that, I have a very bad BMR.