# C# BMR Calculator, improving, refactoring and fix please

Tags: c#, refactoring

I just started my adventure with code few days ago and today I came up with idea to create calories calculator with additional options but i dont know how to add some more specify information like type of work or purpose of the user, if someone can show me how i supose to do it and how its work i will be very grateful.

1.

I want add option that program asking user about type of work, for example something like: [1] - sitting work [2] - standing work [3] - hard psyhical work, and from final result program will multiplication it by [1]1.1 / [2]1.2 or [3]1.4 - can someone help me with that? I will try do same thing with exercises by myself later.

2.

I added additional `if` with text message if someone choose diffrent letter then [f] or [m] the text message shows up and in fact it's working but i dont know why this message is also always showing on the end of program no matter what user choose, can someone show me where i did mistake?

3.

If you have any better solution and think this code is messy, please tell me that, any tips and advices are welcome, sorry for my newbie code and weak english and I promise will work hard everyday to get better.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PROGRAM ZAPOX ver 1.0\n=====================\nWelcome in BMR calculator\nby NoxaGen\n=====================");

            string gender;
            Console.Write("[m] - Male\n[f] - Female\nWhat is your gender?: ");
            gender = Console.ReadLine();



            if (gender == "m")
            {
                Console.Write("Your weight in kilograms: ");
                double manWeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Your height in centymeters: ");
                double manHeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Your age: ");
                int manAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                //Console.Write("What kind of work you do? \nMostly sitting all day (example: work in office) press [1]\n Im sitting and standing (example: teacher) press [2]\nHard psyhical work (example: lumber) press [3] ");
                //i want instal something similiar to this one, and from the main result if [1] then main result * 1.2 / if [2] main result 1.5 etc




                Console.WriteLine("Your basic metabolic rate is arround: " + ((66 + (13.7 * manWeight) + (5 * manHeight) - (6.8 * manAge))) + " calories");
                //double allInfo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                //Console.Write("What is your goal?\n");
                //I also want to add 3 options  - lose weight - maintance - and gain weight, and result after ask Work will substract 500 calories, add 500 or do nothing if maintance

            }
            if (gender == "f")
            {
                Console.Write("Your weight in kilograms: ");
                double womanWeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Your height in centimeters: ");
                double womanHeight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Your age:  ");
                int womanAge = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Your basic metabolic rate is arround:  " + ((655 + (9.6 * womanWeight) + (1.8 * womanHeight) - (4.7 * womanAge))) + " calories");

            }



            if (gender != "f" || gender != "m")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong gender operator! You can choose only between female [f] or male [m]\n" +
                    "if you're flying sphagetti monster i feel sorry :(");
            }



            //if (gender == "k")


            //Console.WriteLine((9.6 + (9.6 * womanWeight) + (1.8 * womanHeight) - (4.7 * womanAge)));


            Console.ReadLine();





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest a basic c# tutorial to begin with and you can learn about the basics alike methods, loops,conditions etc which will help you. Quick search showed [this site](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-tutorial.html) might help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59156866/14171304

Answer (score 1):

Might look little long. But I tried following as much as possible clean code practices. I enjoyed it refactoring

```
public class Program
{
    private const char INVALID_GENDER = '\0';
    private static void Main()
    {
        PrintWelcome();
        Person person = ReadPersonInformation();
        PrintMetabolicRate(person.GetMetabolicRate());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintWelcome()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PROGRAM ZAPOX ver 1.0\n=====================\nWelcome in BMR calculator\nby NoxaGen\n=====================");
    }
    private static Person ReadPersonInformation()
    {
        Person person = null;

        var gender = ReadGender();

        if (gender == INVALID_GENDER)
        {
            return new NullPerson();
        }

        var weight = ReadWeight();
        var height = ReadHeight();
        var age = ReadAge();
        var typeOfWork = ReadTypeOfWork();

        if (gender == 'm')
        {
            person = new Male(weight, height, age, typeOfWork);
        }
        else
        {
            person = new Female(weight, height, age, typeOfWork);
        }
        return person;
    }
    private static double ReadGender()
    {
        Console.Write("[m] - Male\n[f] - Female\nWhat is your gender?: ");

        var gender = Console.ReadLine()[0];
        if (gender != 'm' && gender != 'f')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong gender operator! You can choose only between female [f] or male [m]\n" +
                "if you're flying sphagetti monster i feel sorry :(");
            Console.ReadLine();
            gender = INVALID_GENDER;
        }
        return gender;
    }
    private static double ReadWeight()
    {
        Console.Write("Your weight in kilograms: ");
        return Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private static double ReadHeight()
    {
        Console.Write("Your height in centymeters: ");
        return Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private static double ReadAge()
    {
        Console.Write("Your age: ");
        return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private static TypeOfWork ReadTypeOfWork()
    {
        Console.Write("What kind of work you do? \nMostly sitting all day (example: work in office) press [1]\n Im sitting and standing (example: teacher) press [2]\nHard psyhical work (example: lumber) press [3] ");
        var workTypeValue = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return (TypeOfWork)workTypeValue;
    }
    private static void PrintMetabolicRate(double metabolicRate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your basic metabolic rate is arround: " + metabolicRate + " calories");
        Console.WriteLine("thanks... :)");
    }

}


public abstract class Person
{
    protected double weight;
    protected double height;
    protected double age;
    protected TypeOfWork typeOfWork;

    public Person(double weight, double height, double age, TypeOfWork typeOfWork)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.age = age;
        this.typeOfWork = typeOfWork;
    }

    public abstract double GetMetabolicRate();

    protected double GetCoefficient()
    {
        return this.typeOfWork switch
        {
            TypeOfWork.SittingWork => 1.1,
            TypeOfWork.StandingWork => 1.5,
            TypeOfWork.HardPsyhicalWork => 1.7,
            _ => 1
        };
    }
}

public class Male: Person
{
    public Male(double weight, double height, double age, TypeOfWork typeOfWork) : base(weight, height, age, typeOfWork)
    {
        
    }

    public override double GetMetabolicRate()
    {
        return GetCoefficient() * (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age));
    }
}

public class Female : Person
{
    public Female(double weight, double height, double age, TypeOfWork typeOfWork) : base(weight, height, age, typeOfWork)
    {

    }

    public override double GetMetabolicRate()
    {
        return GetCoefficient() * (655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age));
    }
}

public class NullPerson : Person
{
    public NullPerson(): base(0,0,0,TypeOfWork.None)
    {

    }

    public override double GetMetabolicRate()
    {
        return 0; //we can throw exception too
    }
}

public enum TypeOfWork : byte
{
    SittingWork = 1,
    StandingWork = 2,
    HardPsyhicalWork = 3,
    None
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Program
    {

        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PROGRAM ZAPOX ver 1.0\n=====================\nWelcome in BMR calculator\nby NoxaGen\n=====================");

            Console.Write("[m] - Male\n[f] - Female\nWhat is your gender?: ");
            var gender = Console.ReadLine()[0];
            if (gender != 'm' && gender!='f')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong gender operator! You can choose only between female [f] or male [m]\n" +
                    "if you're flying sphagetti monster i feel sorry :(");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            Console.Write("Your weight in kilograms: ");
            var weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Your height in centymeters: ");
            var height = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Your age: ");
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("What kind of work you do? \nMostly sitting all day (example: work in office) press [1]\n Im sitting and standing (example: teacher) press [2]\nHard psyhical work (example: lumber) press [3] ");
            var workTypeValue = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var workType = (TypeOfWork)workTypeValue;
            var rate = gender == 'm' ? (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age)) :
                (655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age));
            var coefficient = GetCoefficientByWorkingType(workType);
            Console.WriteLine("Your basic metabolic rate is arround: " + rate*coefficient + " calories");
            Console.WriteLine("thanks... :)");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static double GetCoefficientByWorkingType(TypeOfWork typeOfWork)
        {
            switch (typeOfWork)
            {
                case TypeOfWork.SittingWork:
                    return 1.1;
                case TypeOfWork.StandingWork:
                    return 1.5;
                case TypeOfWork.HardPsyhicalWork:
                    return 1.7;
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    public enum TypeOfWork : byte
    {
        SittingWork=1,
        StandingWork=2,
        HardPsyhicalWork=3
    }
```